# Can't insert data into mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble setting up a connection to a phpMyAdmin database I have created. I am trying to create a sign up page. When a user enters their username and password I want the database to be updated. I'm getting the following error messages:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user: 'root@localhost' (Using password: NO) in W:\www\signup.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in W:\www\signup.php on line 3
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user: 'ODBC@localhost' (Using password: NO) in W:\www\signup.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in W:\www\signup.php on line 10 FailedAccess denied for user: 'ODBC@localhost' (Using password: NO)

Here is my code...

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db   = mysql_select_db("loginpage", $conn);
?>

<?php
    $user = $_POST['n'];
    $pass = $_POST['p'];
    $sql = "INSERT into phplogin (username, password) VALUES (".$user.",'".$pass."')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if(!$query)
        echo "Failed".mysql_error();
    else
        echo "Successful!";
?>
```

Comment: `Access denied for user: 'root@localhost'` connection does not even happen. your username and password are wrong :(

Comment: mysql_ functions are deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead! -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database credentials (root/no password) are invalid.  Best solution would be to use phpMyAdmin to create a new user (preferably with a password) and use that user/password to connect.

Try replacing this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT into phplogin (username, password) VALUES (".$user.",'".$pass."')";
```

with this:

```
$sql = "INSERT into phplogin (username, password) VALUES ('".$user."','".$pass."')";
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin... you mean cPanel? I wouldn't really go into information_schema and add a user manually..

Comment: phpMyAdmin has a nice interface for creating users and granting rights.

Comment: oh wow... used that for years and never even clicked on 'user' tab.. thanks Rob

Comment: You will have to set a username and password to be able to connect.

    `$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","XXXXX");`

Comment: That solved that problem, but has now created another: FailedUnknown column 'Hello' in 'field list' - Hello is what I entered in the name field when i tested the form